# About alternating polynomials an the Rowen's notation

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, polynomials, abstract-algebra, noncommutative-rings

Some definitions...

**Definition 1:** A polynomial $f(X_1,\dots ,X_d)$ is $t$-*linear* if the variables $X_1,\dots ,X_t,\; t\leq d$  appear in all monomials of $f$ and degree of $X_i,\; i=1,2,\dots ,t$ on each monomial is $1$.

**Definition 2:** A polynomial $f(X_1,\dots ,X_i \dots ,X_j,\dots ,X_d)$ is $t$-*alternating* if the following condition holds for each $i,j$ with $1\leq i<j\leq t$: writing $X_i$ in the place of $X_j$ yields $f(\dots ,X_i \dots ,X_j,\dots )=0$.

**Definition 3:** a polynomial $f$ is $t$-*normal* if $f$ is $t$-linear and $t$-alternating.

For Rowen, given $\pi,\sigma$ in $\textrm{Sym}(n)$, the composition $\pi\sigma$ denote, first $\pi$ and then $\sigma$.

Assume throughout this text that $f(X_1,\dots ,X_d)$ is $t$-linear.

**Definition 4:** If $\pi\in \textrm{Sym}(k),\; k\leq t$, define $f_{(k,\pi)}$ as the sum of those monomials of $f$ in which $X_1,\dots ,X_k$ appear in the order $X_{\pi1},\dots ,X_{\pi k}$; write $f_{(k)}$ for $f_{(k,1)}$.

On the book **Polynomial Identities in Ring theory**, in the first chapter, section 1.2 (Facts about Normal Polynomial), Rowen proves the following proposition:

**Proposition 1.2.3:** A $t$-linear polynomial $f$ is $t$-normal iff $(ij)\circ f=-f$ for all $i<j\leq t$.

The implication $(\Rightarrow)$ is OK. But in the implication $(\Leftarrow)$, Rowen makes the following affirmation ''Suppose $(ij)\circ f$ for all $i<j\leq t$. Then, writing $f=\sum_{\pi \in \textrm{Sym}(t)}f_{(t,\pi)}$, we have $(ij)\circ f_{(t,\pi)}=-f_{(t,(ij)\pi)}$ for all $\pi \in \textrm{Sym}(t)$.''

I did not understand if the notation $(ij)\circ f_{(t,\pi)}$ means $[(ij)\circ f]_{(t,\pi)}$ or $(ij)\circ [f_{(t,\pi)}]$.

See it...

Suppose that $(ij)\circ f_{(t,\pi)}$ means $(ij)\circ [f_{(t,\pi)}]$. The polynomial 
$$f(X_1,X_2,X_3)=X_1X_2X_3 + X_2X_3X_1 + X_3X_1X_2 - X_1X_3X_2 - X_2X_1X_3 - X_3X_2X_1$$

is $3$-linear and for all $i,j$ such that $i<j\leq 3$, we have $(ij)\circ f=-j$. For $(ij)=(12)$ and $\pi=(132)$, we have $(ij)\circ f_{(t,\pi)}=(12)\circ f_{(3,\pi)}=(12)\circ [f_{(3,\pi)}]=X_3X_2X_1$ (since $[f_{(3,\pi)}]=X_3X_1X_2$).

But, since $(12)\pi=(12)(132)=(23)$, we have $-f_{(3,(12)\pi)}=-f_{(3,(23))}=-(-X_1X_3X_2)=X_1X_3X_2$. Thus, $(ij)\circ f_{(t,\pi)}\neq-f_{(t,(ij)\pi)}$. On the other hand, in this example, $[(ij)\circ f]_{(t,\pi)}=-f_{(t,(ij)\pi)}$

Now suppose that $(ij)\circ f_{(t,\pi)}$ means $[(ij)\circ f]_{(t,\pi)}$. On the same page of the book there is a theorem that says...

**Theorem 1.2.5** (ii) $f$ is $t$-normal iff $f=\sum_{\pi\in\textrm{Sym}(t)}(\textrm{sg}\pi)\pi\circ f_{(t)}$.

Assuming that $(ij)\circ f_{(t,\pi)}$ means $[(ij)\circ f]_{(t,\pi)}$, this theorem does not apply to the polynomial
$$P_t(X_1,\dots ,X_t)=\sum_{\pi \in \textrm{Sym}(t)}(\textrm{sg}\pi)X_{\pi1}\cdots X_{\pi t}.$$

Something is wrong, but do not know what it is. Could anyone help me with this please? What does it means $(ij)\circ f_{(t,\pi)}$?

Sorry for my english. Thank you.

Comment: You forgot to mention the ground field. Obviously, 1.2.3 does not work in characteristic 2. Otherwise, both 1.2.3 and 1.2.5 are well known properties of skew-symmetric tensors. One may speak about $t$-linear forms on $\Bbbk^t$, in which case 1.2.5 is the usual definition of determinant $+$ assertion that the latter is basically unique.

Comment: I think $\sigma \circ f _{(t, \pi)}$ means $\left(\sigma \circ f\right)_{(t, \pi)}$. And I don't see anything wrong with Theorem 1.2.5 (ii).